# Best practice of binding models to backbone views

Tags: backbone.js

I've the following backbone model.

```
var Credential = Backbone.Model.extend({ 

  defaults: {
    user: null,
    password: null
  }
});
```

I want to bind this model to a view.

Is it a best practice to instantiate the `Credential` model from the router and pass to the view

```
var loginView = new LoginView({ model: new Credential() });
```

or instantiate the model in the `initialize` method of the `LoginView`.

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

   initialize: function() {
      this.model = new Credential();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to assign a model to the view, an not let the view create the model.

Conceptually, a view is one representation of a model, when you can have multiple views representing the same model (for instance a form, and a list).

This is why keeping them loosely coupled and assigning a model to a view is usually a better pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There is also one way you can follow. As you may know, backbone view share Controller task from MVC. So you may detach Controller responsibility from view in a independent abstraction, like it made in [Marionette.js](http://www.marionettejs.com/) framework. It this case you will have workflow as following:

1) Controller is in charge of creating and delete views and models, models fetch, providing models to views.

2) Views listen to model events, DOM events and render actual model data

3) Model is only in charge of working with data